# hangfire database not created after install

Tags: hangfire

I installed the hangfire with Nuget.

```
PM> Install-Package Hangfire
```

Then updated the OWIN Startup class with the following lines:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("MySqlConnection");

    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    app.UseHangfireServer();
}
```

I named the connection string name on the web.config as the name of the connectionString In UseSqlServerStorage.

web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CRMModelContext.csdl|res://*/CRMModelContext.ssdl|res://*/CRMModelContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=xxx;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="MySqlConnection" connectionString="User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=xxx;Password=123;Integrated Security=False;Data Source=." />
```

SQL Server 2008 R2 is installed on the system but The database for the hangfire is not in it.

Finally, when I run the program, the error below.

My Job:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<Receiver>(x=>x.EmailReceiving());
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<Receiver>(x => x.EmailReceiving(), Cron.MinuteInterval(15));
```

error:

```
 JobStorage.Current property value has not been initialized. You must set it before using Hangfire Client or Server API.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("MySqlConnection");` is using `MySqlConnection` as a connection string, not the value of `MySqlConnection`!

Are you using MsSql Server or MySql Server?

Try :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnection"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: using from MsSql Server. i use from your code but still get Same error: JobStorage.Current property value has not been initialized...

Comment: Add this before `var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnection"].ConnectionString` and what is the content of `connectionString`?

Comment: I checked now. The tables are made in the database, but I also get that error

Comment: Check that connection is valid.  Check where the error occurs, this is after hangfire has been initialized.

Comment: i call BackgroundJob.Enqueue<Receiver>(x=>x.EmailReceiving()) , RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<Receiver>(x => x.EmailReceiving(), Cron.MinuteInterval(15)) in the application_start() in global.asax. error occured on these .

Comment: First, they run and then go to startup.
I want to get emails every 15 minutes with these jobs. Is his place suitable?

Comment: No because `global.asax application start()` is called before `public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)`  Simply move after hangfire initialization in startup.cs file).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

I had struggled to find the right solution online, then after asking around, I realized that I should create the datatable on the server by myself, then the tables will be created by hangfire after the application started.

Basically, there are 3 main lines of code that I put in my application to make the hangfire works:(.netcore web application) (in the startup.cs)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ......
    string connectionString = "getYourConnectionStringHere";
    services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(connectionString));
    services.AddHangfireServer();
    ...... 
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ....
    app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire"); //this is to set the url for hangfire, e.g. localhost://xxxx/hangfire
    ...
}
```

Comment: `Correct me if I'm wrong`: If you're using SQL Server, you might also consider adding the Login into the DDLAdmin role for the database in question (DataWriter is not sufficient), or creating the schema yourself: https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html#installing-objects.